# I want to make a global change to my column headers

Tags: python, pandas, replace, header

I import a large CSV file and index my first row as my columns header. This first row is data ex. -170 -170,1 ... and that is wanted. I want the numbers to be separated by dots instead of commas.

I have tried the function replace but does not seem to pick up the header in its function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Vrai.csv', decimal='.', sep=';', index_col=False, encoding='latin-1')

df = df.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```

Here is a sample of the data frame:

```
       -

171     -170,7  -170,4   ...       195,6    195,9    196,2
0      0.000000   0.000000 -57.251   ...    -128.360 -128.501 -128.631
1      0.000000   0.000000 -57.249   ...    -128.366 -128.459 -128.524
2      0.000000   0.000000 -57.222   ...    -128.228 -128.256 -128.294
3      0.000000   0.000000 -57.201   ...    -128.124 -128.162 -128.199
4      0.000000   0.000000 -57.234   ...    -128.234 -128.410 -128.733
```

Comment: Try df.replace(',', '.', regex = True)

Comment: It didn't work. How is it supposed to proceed? @Vaishali

Comment: Can you elaborate? What exact code did you try?

Comment: i just added the line : df.replace(',','.',regex=True) to my code

Comment: replace doesn't work inplace, you need to assign the result to df. df = df.replace(',','.',regex=True) or df.replace(',','.',regex=True, inplace = True)

Comment: Oh i see what you mean, i had already reassigned df but it still does not work.
Here is the exact line : df = df.replace(',','.', regex = True)

Comment: Is the first line with value -170,7.... part of data or column names? If those are column names, you need df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(',','.')

Comment: It was part of column header and it did the trick! Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

To change the commas by periods you can do the following by accessing the column labels of the dataframe through `df.columns` and calling the replace method:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(',','.')
```